# Git add . is failing, complains about non-existent directory

Tags: git, macos

So, I'm getting this error message when running "git add .":

```
git add .
warning: could not open directory '.1a239c90-dae6-f0ef-0af3-093a963e8254.cls/': Permission denied
```

The funny thing is, there is no such directory on my machine...

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: It looks like a journaling artifact for a remote or at least external hard drive

Comment: Would it help to simply run update first ?

Answer (score 0):

It starts with a dot so it is by default hidden from display on UNIX systems and in git bash on windows. Check if it really doesn't exist with ls -a. It seems like a temporary LaTeX file - try to reopen the bash to reload the environment and check the file's flags (if it's really present).

Comment: and you can always try `git rm --cached <filename>`

Comment: That's the weird part, this directory is non-existent. (ls -a does not show it, that's why rm -cached is failing too...)

Comment: it complains about it: git status
warning: could not open directory '.1a239c90-dae6-f0ef-0af3-093a963e8254.cls/': Permission denied

Comment: Try to create a file(or dir) with exact same name (try with the last slash and without it) and manually remove it with `rm -rf`

Comment: If this doesn't help I would: commit+push all files manually -> force delete current directory from parent's level -> git reset hard or git clone if this was the root, and if the problem occurs during removal of directory - (fastest) restart PC to mount and unmount the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing, try and clone your repo elsewhere, and report your modification in that new clone.

From there, you can test if a `git add .` would trigger the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact issue, I have many .1a239c90-dae6-f0ef-0af3-093a963e8254.cls files, they are in multiple repos, I am building and running both from a vagrant environment and from my mac.
I do not yet know what is happening, it just started seemingly out of the blue a couple days ago.
Do not have permission to delete from the command line, even with sudo, I have to manually move them to the trash and input admin creds to delete.